# How to automatically move from e.g. x[1] to x[2]

Tags: r

I have a random vector (of numbers 1:5) of length 20. I need to count the number of runs of 1 (i.e. each number that is not followed by the same number), 2 (i.e. 2 consecutive numbers the same), 3 and 4.

I'm trying to write a function that takes x[1] and x[2] and compares them, if they are the same then + 1 to a counting variable. After that, x[1] becomes x[2] and x[2] should become x[3] so it keeps on repeating. How do I make x[2] change to x[3] without assigning it again? Sorry if that doesn't make much sense

This is my first day learning R so please simplify as much as you can so I understand lol..

```
{
    startingnumber <- x[1]
    nextnumber <- x[2]
    count <- 0

    repeat {
    if (startingnumber == nextnumber) {
        count <- count + 1
        startingnumber <- nextnumber
            nextnumber <- x[3]

    } else {

        if (startingnumber != nextnumber) {
            break
            ........
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just want the rle function?

Comment: Indeed, or rather a frequency table of rle lengths, something like: `table(rle(sample(1:5, 20, rep=TRUE))$lengths)`?

Comment: In "real life", you would not use a loop to do that with R. However, this is probably an exercise about basic R control flow. You need to use a `for` loop, not a bunch nested `if/else`. You need to use a variable to index `x`, instead of hardcoding numbers (e.g. use `x[i]` where `i` is initially 0 and incremented with `i <- i + 1`. Given your questions, I would recommend you follow a basic programming course first, for example on datacamp or codeacademy or the hundreds of similar services.

Comment: For better understanding, it would be great if you could add an example of what the vector could look like, and what the expected outcome in your example is.

Comment: @Sven my vector is 3 1 1 3 4 5 3 1 5 4 2 4 2 3 2 3 2 4 5 4.

My answer would look something like there are 18 runs of 1 and 1 run of 2 (1 1 is the 1 run of 2). The thing that I am having problems with is counting runs above 2. 

Going to try follow the advice from @/antoine-sac and use a for loop and see how that goes for now.

Comment: @user11609172: Is your objective to learn how to use R (conditionals, indexes, for loops etc), or to analyze the data? Both are fine, but how we answer depends on what you want to learn. If you just want to analyze the data the way you describe, there are far more efficient solutions than a for loop.

Comment: @AkselA to analyze the data. Could you tell me some other solutions? I have very little experience with programming so this is pretty hard for me to wrap my head around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using `table()` on the `rle()` lengths is probably the most concise solution

E.g:

```
x <- c(3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4)
table(rle(x)$lengths)
#  1  2 
# 18  1 


# or
v <- c(1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1)
table(rle(v)$lengths)
# 1 2 3
# 6 4 2
```

In the first example there's 18 singles and one double (the two `1`s near the beginning), for a total of `1*18 + 2*1 = 20` values

In the second example there are 6 singles, 4 doubles, and 2 triples, giving a total of `1*6 + 2*4 + 3*2 = 20` values

But if computational speed is of more importance than concise code, we can do better, as both `table()` and `rle()` do computations internally that we don't really need. Instead we can assemble a function that only does the bare minimum.

```
runlengths <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    r <- which(x[-1] != x[-n])
    rl <- diff(c(0, r, n))
    rlu <- sort(unique(rl))
    rlt <- tabulate(match(rl, rlu))
    names(rlt) <- rlu
    as.table(rlt)
}

runlengths(x)
#  1  2 
# 18  1 

runlengths(v)
# 1 2 3 
# 6 4 2
```

---

Bonus:

You already know that you can compare individual elements of a vector like this

```
x[1] == x[2]
x[2] == x[3]
```

but did you know that you can compare vectors with each other, and that you can select multiple elements from a vector by specifying multiple indices? Together that means we can instead of doing

```
x[1] == x[2]
x[2] == x[3]
.
.
.
x[18] == x[19]
x[19] == x[20]
```

do

```
x[1:19] == x[2:20]

# Or even
x[-length(x)] == x[-1]
```